# Outlook: Display the envelope icon in the tray after a certain time

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I want Outlook to display the new email envelope icon in the system tray only after a new email has been received and it is in unread state for more than X minutes (like 1 hour). Is there a way to achieve this? The reason I ask for this is to reduce distractions.

Comment: You could change the sync frequency, so that emails are only collected every hour. See Here: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/check-for-new-email-frequency

Comment: ...and If you're using an Exchange-based account you can go offline to prevent distraction from new mail (send/receive settings don't affect Exchange accounts). I have a client that does this to avoid the distraction of new mail.

Answer (score 0):

#### Nope.

I understand your concern but no option available to control the behavior.

Comment: Can you support that statement with positive evidence?

Comment: Couldn't this be done with some VBA?